# What is the superflip on 15-puzzle?

Tags: optimization, sliding-blocks

On the 15-puzzle, what (solvable) position takes the most moves to solve if you solve it optimally?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The hardest positions on the 15-puzzle require $80$ moves to solve (where a move consists of sliding a single tile). Here is an example of a position requiring $80$ moves:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
15&14&8&12\\\hline
10&11&9&13\\\hline
2&6&5&1\\\hline
3&7&4&\\\hline
\end{array}
$$
This position (and several others) can be found in Ralph Gasser's PhD thesis from 1995 [G], where it is proved that $80$ moves are necessary. A few years later, it was proved in [BMFN] that no position requires more moves. Both proofs are aided by computers.

---

[BMFN] Brüngger, Adrian; Marzetta, Ambros; Fukuda, Komei; Nievergelt, Jurg. The parallel search bench ZRAM and its applications. *Ann. Oper. Res.* **90** (1999), 45-63.

[G] Gasser, Ralph Udo. Harnessing Computational Resources
for Efficient Exhaustive Search. PhD Thesis, ETH Zürich, 1995.

Comment: A note on this answer: the position here assumes that the blank goes in **upper left** corner in the final position. A complete list of positions requiring $80$ moves, as well as an optimal solver, is available [on this site](http://kociemba.org/themen/fifteen/fifteensolver.html) (I'm not the author, just found it by searching).